# Find formulas for the entries of Mn, where n is a positive integer

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[Find formulas for the entries of Mn, where n is a positive integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZASLY.jpg)

I found the eigenvalues then the eigenvectors then did
$ PD^nP^-1 $
My answer is still wrong somehow.

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: Can you state the eigenvalues and eigenvectors you found?

Comment: Eigenvector for value 5: (-2 1)
Eigenvector for value 2: (-1 1)

Comment: Yes this is what I got too. I used your eigenvalues and vectors and got the following below

Comment: Turns out I wrote the P matrix wrong. Thank you for the correction. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors stated above we get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}8&6\\-3&-1\end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix}-2&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\1&2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-2\cdot5^n&-2^n\\5^n&2^n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\1&2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 \cdot 5^n - 2^n&2 \cdot5^n - 2^{n+1}\\2^n-5^n&2^{n+1}-5^n\end{pmatrix}.$$

where $P = \begin{pmatrix}-2&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ so $P^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$.